# Aplication error no heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, heroku

Fiz uma aplicação utilizando o IntelliJ usando banco de dados e tá tudo funcionando muito bem, mas assim que dei o *push* para o Heroku me apareceu uma mensagem:

> Application Error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

Usei o comando `heroku logs` no terminal mas não consegui identificar o erro, alguém saberia dizer?

```
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359785+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hib
ernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not close connection
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359791+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSetting
sAdapter.onStop(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:26) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.1
1-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359789+00:00 app[web.1]:    at Global.onStop(Global.java:30)
~[series-app.series-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359787+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransacti
on(JPA.java:111) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java-jpa_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359792+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStop(
GlobalSettings.scala:227) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359794+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$stop$1
$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(Play.scala:108) [com.typesafe.pl
ay.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359796+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.
GenericJDBCException: Could not close connection
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359800+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi
.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[org.hibernate.hiberna
te-core-4.2.3.Final.jar:4.2.3.Final]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359802+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi
.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[org.hibernate.hiberna
te-core-4.2.3.Final.jar:4.2.3.Final]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359798+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.exception.inter
nal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.2.3.Final.jar:4.2.3.Final]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359808+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
tJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]

2015-02-13T11:35:27.359803+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.int
ernal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:245) ~[
org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.2.3.Final.jar:4.2.3.Final]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359810+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
t(DbException.java:172) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359805+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.int
ernal.LogicalConnectionImpl.close(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:168) ~[org.hibernat
e.hibernate-core-4.2.3.Final.jar:4.2.3.Final]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359811+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
t(DbException.java:149) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359813+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
t(DbException.java:138) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359814+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.ch
eckClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1413) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
2015-02-13T11:35:27.359806+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLExcep
tion: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, a
dd ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-175]
2015-02-13T11:35:28.246656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-02-13T11:35:30.570487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `t
arget/universal/stage/bin/series-app -Dhttp.port=${PORT}-DapplyEvolutions.defaul
t=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
-Djpa.default=postgrePersistenceUnit`
2015-02-13T11:35:32.461439+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx38
4m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-02-13T11:35:33.020562+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 3
2015-02-13T11:35:34.300613+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302414+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.play
$api$db$BoneCPPlugin$$dbApi(DB.scala:211)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302401+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Configuration$.play$
api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302418+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302428+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.StaticApplication.<
init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302404+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Configuration.report
Error(Configuration.scala:743)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302420+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.collection.immutable.Li
st.foreach(List.scala:383)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.301266+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration error: Configuration
error[Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=postgres://qasmxh
feaayqwg:3WEhsl_y4vIidnGpvSiZqaH0iO@ec2-54-163-254-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54
32/df072ps3a73i88]]
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302423+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302405+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.registe
r(DB.scala:285)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302421+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302407+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.createD
ataSource(DB.scala:300)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302415+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onSt
art(DB.scala:238)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302479+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302409+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.setupDa
tasources(DB.scala:411)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302417+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302481+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala
:145)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302410+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.<init>(
DB.scala:418)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302424+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302476+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
.createServer(NettyServer.scala:244)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302412+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.play
$api$db$BoneCPPlugin$$dbApi$lzycompute(DB.scala:211)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302427+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.sca
la:90)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302491+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Nati
ve Method)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302478+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302587+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.registe
r(DB.scala:280)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302514+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class
.java:340)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302482+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302483+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer.
main(NettyServer.scala)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302676+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 more
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302426+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.utils.Threads$.withConte
xtClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
2015-02-13T11:35:34.302489+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundE
xception: org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=postgres://qasmxhfeaayqwg:3WEhsl
_y4vIidnGpvSiZqaH0iO@ec2-54-163-254-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/df072ps3a73i
88
2015-02-13T11:35:35.208037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2015-02-13T11:35:35.221514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-02-13T11:35:35.222364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-02-13T11:35:41.599821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `t
arget/universal/stage/bin/series-app -Dhttp.port=${PORT}-DapplyEvolutions.defaul
t=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
-Djpa.default=postgrePersistenceUnit`
2015-02-13T11:35:44.657952+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx38
4m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2015-02-13T11:35:46.126953+00:00 app[web.1]: Play server process ID is 3
2015-02-13T11:35:49.739897+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Configuration$.play$
api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.734006+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2015-02-13T11:35:49.739967+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Configuration.report
Error(Configuration.scala:743)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.740017+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.registe
r(DB.scala:285)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745068+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.setupDa
tasources(DB.scala:411)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745179+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.play
$api$db$BoneCPPlugin$$dbApi$lzycompute(DB.scala:211)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.740054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.createD
ataSource(DB.scala:300)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745120+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.<init>(
DB.scala:418)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745269+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onSt
art(DB.scala:238)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745226+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.play
$api$db$BoneCPPlugin$$dbApi(DB.scala:211)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745740+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.collection.immutable.Li
st.foreach(List.scala:383)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745316+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745807+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.762578+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.sca
la:90)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745364+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745860+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.762513+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.utils.Threads$.withConte
xtClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.745897+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$
1.apply(Play.scala:91)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.762623+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.StaticApplication.<
init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.762677+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
.createServer(NettyServer.scala:244)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763750+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundE
xception: org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=postgres://qasmxhfeaayqwg:3WEhsl
_y4vIidnGpvSiZqaH0iO@ec2-54-163-254-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/df072ps3a73i
88
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763802+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Nati
ve Method)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.764524+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class
.java:340)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.762736+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763316+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763365+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala
:145)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763405+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer$
.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.763466+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.NettyServer.
main(NettyServer.scala)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.764676+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 21 more
2015-02-13T11:35:49.764602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.registe
r(DB.scala:280)
2015-02-13T11:35:49.734575+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration error: Configuration
error[Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver-Ddb.default.url=postgres://qasmxh
feaayqwg:3WEhsl_y4vIidnGpvSiZqaH0iO@ec2-54-163-254-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54
32/df072ps3a73i88]]
2015-02-13T11:35:50.843732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2015-02-13T11:35:50.849947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-02-13T11:37:27.060248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=c18e3cb7-782a
-4def-b22b-b72ee7745fde fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service= status=503
bytes=
2015-02-13T11:44:46.784896+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by erick.rodrig
ues@ccc.ufcg.edu.br
2015-02-13T11:44:46.784896+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy dcb352d by erick.rodrigues@
ccc.ufcg.edu.br
2015-02-13T11:44:47.146430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to do
wn
2015-02-13T11:45:51.770520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=
d75d19b3-769a-47a5-bc1e-0f8609a718db fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-13T11:50:11.167173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=
133bac21-c86d-4261-b18d-d29c85097743 fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-13T11:50:13.466527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=
5be0632b-6b5c-4dd1-9f56-01d860a28a4d fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-13T11:50:14.655216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=
09c7a6cc-785f-4e55-bb34-18764cb30638 fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-13T11:50:15.966836+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=app-series.herokuapp.com request_id=
ad832459-5512-4564-95f0-163d2dcea6fc fwd="186.212.141.71" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
```

Segue o arquivo procfile caso necessário

```
target/universal/stage/bin/series-app -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Djpa.default=postgrePersistenceUnit
```

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem **Driver not found** do log indica que falta o driver do postgre no seu *classpath*.

Comment: Como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: @Erick Adicione o driver na sua aplicação.

Comment: Ok, mas eu não sei como adicionar o driver e tal, to aprendendo ainda e só sei o básico. Agradeço se tu puder dizer um passo a passo.

Comment: @Erick Não tem como fazer um passo-a-passo porque não tenho nenhuma informação sobre a estrutura do seu projeto. Se você usa Maven, pode fazer algo parecido com o que tem [nesta pergunta do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14797896/1683070), isto é, declarar o driver do postgre como uma dependência e depois incluir as dependências no pacote gerado.

Comment: E também não sou especialista em configuração do Heroku.